# Instance of c++ class

Tags: c++, class, object

**In the below code what does "a"  and "&a" contains?**

```
class list{
};
int main(){
    list *a= new list();
    cout<<"\n Values:a="<<a<<" & &a="<<&a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a pointer to the object list which is allocated on heap.
basically `a` contains an address(pointer stores an address,if you are aware).
And `&a` does not contain anything.what you are doing is actually taking the address of that pointer and printing it.

Answer (score 5):

`a` is a pointer to an object of type `list`.

`&a` is the address of the pointer `a`.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is pointer to the `list` object (allocated generally in free-store). Content of `a` is changeable.

`&a` is address of `a` (where `a` resides in memory layout). `&a` is not changeable.

Answer (score 2):

Writing the `&` left to a variable gives you the address of this variable. This is essentially the same as a pointer to the potion of memory, this variable is stored in.

Since `a` is already a pointer, `&a` is a pointer to a pointer.

So in your example `a` contains the memory address of a `list` as a numeric value. `&a` is also a numeric value, which contains the memory address, where the pointer `a` is stored.

Answer (score 1):

`a` contains a pointer to the object you `new`ed, and `&a` doesn't contain anything, since it's not an object (lvalue, in C++ parlance), just an expression.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a pointer to an object of type list dynamically allocated on freestore(heap)
`&a` is the address of the pointer.